# Visual Studio Cannot Find .cs

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I am just starting to learn ASP.NET (C#) and I am struggling with a tutorial I am working on.

I have my App_Code Folder and within it, I have a folder called DataAccessStuff. Within this folder are a bunch of .cs files I will be using for the data layer of things.

The problem is, Visual Studio is unable to detect the location of these .cs files and gives me the error:

```
"The type name "DataAccessStuff does not exist in the type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.Content"
```

I have no idea how to get it to recognize. I simply copied the project file from the textbook CD onto my computer as it said. I have attached images showing the precise tree layout of the project as well as the code I am using. If anyone can please help a beginner out, it would be appreciated.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Inside one of the .cs files

[image]

Comment: Try including the full name of the namespace. Because otherwise the application is referring the .NET Namespace of similar name.

Comment: can you open these cs files, and confirm their namespace

Comment: As another note, App_Code has a very specific purpose.  Are you sure that these files should even be there in the first place?

Comment: Open up the files, for example ArtistDA.cs and look at what the namespace is.  C# doesn't automatically assign a namespace based on the folder in which the cs file resides.

Comment: @BrijRajSingh Thanks for the quick reply, How can I go about to confirm these name spaces? What am I looking for exactly? Thanks

Comment: just like @JohnKoerner is saying, open the files, and and check the namesoace

Comment: @BrijRajSingh The file (AbstractDA.cs) says "namespace Content.DataAccessStuff". It seems to be correct. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us the top few lines of code from one of the code files in the `DataAccessStuff` folder please?

Comment: Are the files set to compile? Check the file properties and have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The namespace is probably

```
Content.DataAccessStuff
```

based on the root name of your project.  However, if you simply double click the file in DataAccessStuff that you want to access, it will give you the namespace of the file.

**EDIT:** Since this is a Web Site Project, not a Web Application Project, namespacing is by default not explicit unless added.

Make sure anything referencing something belonging to the folder Content.DataAccessStuff has a

```
using Content.DataAccessStuff;
```

at the top of the class with the rest of your using statements.

The following article does an excellent job highlighting some of the key differences between Web Site Projects and Web Application Projects.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Comment: The file (AbstractDA.cs) says "namespace Content.DataAccessStuff". It seems to be correct. Any other suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I apologize for how simple this may be but when I right click the .cs file, there is no option for properities. All I see is open, open with, scope to this, new solution explorer view, cut, copy, delete... I do see a properties "window" but it only contains the fileName with the fullPath. Once again, I am running VS 2012. Any other suggestions? Thanks for your help, really appreciated

Comment: @Teddy13 No problem :). First, to clarify, you are selecting the AbstractDA.cs filename in Solution Explorer.  You can also select the filename and hit "Alt+Enter" on your keyboard to bring up the properties window.  There should be two sections, Advanced and Misc.  Build Action is the second option in Advanced.

Comment: I did all that and once again same properties window that only contains "FileName" and "FullPath". It also contains options such as "categorized" and "alphabetical". Interesting though, I removed the "using Content.DataAccessStuff" and put instead of that "namespace Content.DataAccessStuff" (as well as added my two braces), and the error has gone away. Is this the same thing as "using" or have done something completely different? Thanks

Comment: You've now namespaced your TestDataAccess class to be the same as your AbstractDA.cs class, which is masking the problem, not correcting it. :)

Comment: Ahhh I thought it was solved! Do you want me to screen shot the property window or is that irrelevant at this point? Thanks

Comment: No, my suspicion is that you actually created a Web SITE instead of a Web APPLICATION.  Is that correct?  If so, you don't be able to set the Build Action.  In that case, simply move all of your files in App_Code into a new folder outside of App_Code.  It doesn't look like it's appropriate to keep it there and you'll have slightly better control over the file at that point :).

Comment: Another thing, I have an error message that says: The type or namespace name "Content" could not be found(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: And yes that is correct! I will try that now and let you know

Comment: So just to clarify, I am moving the entire DataAccess folder outside of App_code and into for example just lab6? or is it the individual .cs files I am moving?

Comment: I apologize...my last advice was probably poor.  It's been a while since I've worked with a web site application.  You should be able to leave it there.  When you try to instantiate a new instance of AbstractDA without the "using Content.DataAccessStuff" inclusing at the top, does it work?  Simply doing new AbstractDA();

Comment: Not a problem, I really appreciate you trying to help :) And no, it gives me an erorr see it can't find AbstractDa ... I've added a screenshot to one of the .cs classes in my answer. Perhaps it will be of help? Thanks

Comment: Btw the name of the tutorials are Web applications so maybe it is a web app? Right now I am confused between a web app and a web site. Web site is static while web app something is happening (AKA communicating with a server from user input)? Because I am working on "web forms"

Comment: See my updates that will hopefully provide some clarity ;).  The article link is a bit technical but provides an excellent explanation on the differences.

Comment: I will take a look at it. I tried declaring the AbstractDA() the way you showed in the example but it even complained about "var" saying that namespace could not be found. I am starting to think something more serious is going on?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/40796/discussion-between-david-l-and-teddy13)

Answer (score 0):

Check the namespace provided in all the class (.cs files) of 'DataAccessStuff' folder.

It should be 'Content.DataAccessStuff'.

Answer (score 0):

write using lab6.DataAccessStuff instead of Content.

Comment: The type or namespace name "lab6" could not be found. It gives me that error message. Thanks!

Comment: right click on c:\...\lab6, properties -> application -> name